# why does the mouse outrun the modal window in this Angular draggable example on plunker

Tags: angularjs

[Here is an example](http://embed.plnkr.co/8CHoiN/preview) of a draggable modal window in Angular (from another author, not me).

On my monitor at work, and on my monitor at home, when the modal is dragged left-to-right or right-to-left on a wide screen, the mouse "outruns" the window, and the mouse pointer ends up outside the modal window. What causes this behavior?

Comment: also for smaller screens it resizes instead of dragging...i would not use this library...i would use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ instead

Comment: suspect it is a conflict with bootstrap.js

Comment: @Logan Murphy: I have the angular bootstrap UI installed, but I cannot get bootstrap modal to be draggable with the Angular native directive implementation of draggable found here: // Draggable directive from: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler   -- and I'm seeing if I can get by without using jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `bottom` and `right` css attributes added by the `.modal` class of Bootstrap using the javascript like so.

```
function mousemove(event) {
  y = event.screenY - startY;
  x = event.screenX - startX;
  element.css({
    top: y + 'px',
    left: x + 'px',
    bottom : 'auto',
    right : 'auto'
  });
}
```

Comment: The draggable directive is not detecting the mousedown event. I think the AngularUI implementation of bootstrap modal window may be swallowing the mousedown.

Comment: all you need to do is change the contents of the mouse move event to the code above...everything else should remain the same

Comment: The problem was, I was applying the draggable to the modal rather than to the html template it comprises, so the mousedown event was never being received by the draggable directive.

Comment: No, not "fine".  With or without the code you suggested, the modal window can be dragged around, but it leaves its drop-shadow behind. The shadow stays in the window's original position.

Comment: So you are saying there is a shadow behind the modal that is the same size as the modal...but when you move the modal the shadow doesn't move with it? which browser / version are you using? the code above solves the original problem which is the cursor outrunning the modal as you move it. Also i do not see the behavior you describe.

Comment: Chrome and IE both same behavior. I've opened up a separate question with relevant code showing how I'm doing the modal and indicating that it should be draggable: stackoverflow.com/questions/25889745/ui-bootstrap-modal-drop-shadow-does-not-follow-dragged-modal-window